# try/catch missing vector subscript out of range (debug assertion failed)

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, try-catch

I have some code, where I'm using `std::forward_list`
Part of my code tests for vector subscripts being out of range, as well as if the element in the vector has certain properties (in this case, is not -1).
When I have just the first or second node of the list, it works fine and I can catch the error, as that's just a normal part of the program. However, on the next loop around, when I have 3 elements in the list, I get the `vector subscript out of range` debug assertion, and it isn't caught by my `try/catch`.  Is there a different technique I must use to resolve this error?
Here's a snippet of the code, where it's problematic:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if(curr->moves[i].at(0) >= 0 && curr->moves[i].at(1) >= 0)
            {
                next->setPos(curr->moves[i].at(0),curr->moves[i].at(1)); //just sets values of a vector
                next->setMoves(); //sets values of a 2d vector
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    try{if(board.kBoard[next->moves[i].at(0)][next->moves[i].at(1)] != -1)  //the debug assertion is thrown here, but I cannot catch it
                            next->moves[i].at(2) = 1;}
                    catch(out_of_range const &err)
                        {next->moves[i].at(2) = 1;}
                }
            ...
          }
     }
```

I've commented where the issue occurs. You'll (at least on my screen) have to scroll to the right to see it.  I believe that, potentially, I can use another catch statement, but I don't know which error to use, given that I'm already using `out_of_range`, which normally would handle this issue.  A screenshot of what the error looks like when it's thrown is [this](https://gyazo.com/72380b93f7c8adadd0f1a54edbc04589).  To be completely clear, the issue occurs at `try{if(board.kBoard[next->moves[i].at(0)][next->moves[i].at(1) != -1)`, where I have commented. It doesn't go to the `catch` statement at all, I think because it's using `_DEBUG_ERROR()`

Comment: Are you sure it is the try catch that is the problem?  You are also using `at` in the catch block which can throw and `board.kBoard[curr->moves[great].at(0)][curr->moves[great].at(1)] = wR + 1;` which can also throw

Comment: Well, I am expecting the `at` to throw. However, when I debug the code, as soon as I have 3 elements in my list and I execute the line `if(board.kBoard[next->moves[i].at(0)][next->moves[i].at(1)] != -1)`, I get the error. And there is a vector subscript that's out of range, I know that; however, it doesn't get caught.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @SidS I removed some code, to only include the specific loop(s) where the error occurs.

Comment: @Adam, Right, so add some code to make it verifiable.  You're making this a guessing game.

Comment: @SidS I have added what you requested.  It should be very crystal clear specifically where the error is occurring, and what the error looks like when I encounter it.

Comment: Dealing with subscript being out of range by trying to catch that exception is like dealing with a car that's leaking gas by attaching a bucket under the gas tank, and not doing anything about the actual hole in the gas tank. It doesn't make much sense. How about fixing the code so that it doesn't try to use out-of-range subscripts. A vector will happily tell you how many values it has, just for asking what its `size()` is. Doesn't it make more sense to check `size()`, first, and determine whether your subscript is in range, or not?

Comment: @Adam, what I requested was a [mcve].  You did not add that, and there is nothing even remotely clear in your code.  Your code has plenty of array accesses outside the try block, it has several inside the try block, and it even redoes some of it inside the catch block.  Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are right. I actually came to the same conclusion you did, when thinking about the flow of my code in general.  There's no reason to use a try/catch when I'm just testing if vector subscripts are out of range, since that is possible without allowing errors through the code.  I'm going to write up an answer, to help people avoid these kinds of codeflows in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, theoretically, a `try/catch` statement could catch the error here, it isn't wise to intentionally cause errors as part of an algorithm; `try/catch` should be used to report when errors happen.  In this case, I should have used:

```
if(next->moves[i].at(0) >= 0 && next->moves[i].at(1) >= 0) //1
    if(board.kBoard[next->moves[i].at(0)][next->moves[i].at(1)] != -1) //2
        next->moves[i].at(2) = 1; //3
else
    next->moves[i].at(2) = 1; //3
```

This allows me to check if the subscript is out of range (1), check if an element of the board is not -1 (2), and set `moves[i].at(2)` to 1, in those cases (3).
This avoids any `out_of_range` errors, obviating the need for `try/catch` entirely.